# <a> tag doesn't navigate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have anchor tag, i wanted to be hidden when clicked, i found a solution online however when i click am not redirected to the target URL?

and is there a way to replace with loading, searching in this site i could find many to replace button but not anchor tag

```
<a id="startClick" class="btn btn-start animated fadeInUpBig" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home",new{id=0})">Start now</a>
```

script

```
$(function () {
    $("#startClick").click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: when you want to navigate from the page then what is purpose to hide a anchor link?

Comment: Good question! the reason i'm doing that is because it take sometimes to load the target page, and as i mentioned my next step is to display loading  inplace of the anchor link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `return false` from the click event. It prevents the navigation of link.

```
$("#startClick").click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning false in a click event will stop the navigation. If you remove that, the browser will take you to the URL.